# Project Mongo collection array value under a condition

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

i am using the Mongo php library in a service that is responsible of storing and retrieving some social data, specifically from Facebook, and just a snippet, it goes something like this, a collection of posts insights:

```
{
  "_id":"5865aa8e9bbbe400010f97a2",
  "insights":[  
     {  
        "name":"post_story_adds_unique",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":10
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"post_story_adds",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":11
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":{  
                 "like":10,
                 "comment":1
              }
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"post_story_adds_by_action_type",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":{  
                 "like":10,
                 "comment":1
              }
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"post_impressions_unique",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":756
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
},
{ 

  "_id":"586d939b9bbbe400010f9f12",
  "insights":[  
     {  
        "name":"post_story_adds_unique",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":76
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"post_story_adds",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":85
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":{  
                 "like":73,
                 "comment":8,
                 "share":2
              }
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"post_story_adds_by_action_type",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":{  
                 "like":74,
                 "comment":9,
                 "share":2
              }
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"post_impressions_unique",
        "period":"lifetime",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "value":9162
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

We can note that all the posts' sub-documents, i.e. metrics, are present in each post, surely, with their corresponding values.
I believe that the data structure presented above is not optimal to work with; if faced with the situation to project a couple of these sub-documents values, say `post_story_adds_by_action_type`'s and `post_impressions_unique`'s `value` property, we need to run a condition on all the sub-documents in order to match the `name` property to `post_story_adds_by_action_type` or `post_impressions_unique`.

I tried `$elemMatch(projection)`, but as the documentation says, it only returns the first matching array element. I was able to do so as such:

```
$this->db->$collection->find([],
    [
        'projection' => [
            'insights' => [
                '$elemMatch' => [
                    'name' => 'post_impressions_unique'
                ]
            ],
            '_id' => 0,
            'insights.values.value' => 1,
        ],
    ]);
```

A `MongoDB\Driver\Cursor` object is returned with only the desired value, by setting this `'insights.values.value' => 1`, of the sub-documents that have `name` equal to `post_impressions_unique`.

The first thing i thought about was, of course, to use the `$or` logical operator:

```
$this->db->$collection->find([],
    [
      'projection' => [
          'insights' => [
              '$elemMatch' => [
                    '$or' => [
                        [
                          'name' => [
                              '$eq' => 'post_story_adds_by_action_type',
                          ]
                        ],
                        [
                          'name' => [
                              '$eq' => 'post_impressions_unique',
                          ]
                        ]
                    ]

                  ]
              ]
          ],
          '_id' => 0,
          'insights.name' => 1,
          'insights.values.value.like' => 1,
          'insights.values.value' => 1,
    ]);
```

> Note the projections `'insights.values.value.share' => 1` `'insights.values.value' => 1` corresponding to the different sub-documents value position.

Of course this didn't work, i got an array of `post_impressions_unique` sub-documents alone; so i had to try the aggregation framework https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/ :

```
$this->db->$name->aggregate(
  [
      [
      '$project' => [
          'insights' => [
              '$filter' => [
                'input' => '$insights',
                'as' => 'name',
                'cond' => [
                    '$or' => [
                      [
                        '$eq' => [
                            'name', '$post_story_adds_by_action_type',
                            ]
                      ],
                      [
                        '$eq' => [
                            'name', '$post_impressions_unique',
                        ]
                      ],
                    ],
                ],
              ],
          ],
          '_id' => 0,
          'values.value.like' => 1,
          'values.value' => 1,
        ],
      ]
  ]);
```

This didn't work either, in this case i got an array of empty `insights` objects.

I considered using the [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package and take advantage of the Eloquent builder.

`DB::collection($collection)->project(['insights' => ['$elemMatch' => ['name' => 'post_story_adds_unique']]])->get();`

or

```
DB::collection($collection)->project(['insights' => [
                '$filter' => [
                    'input' => '$insights',
                    'as' => 'name',
                    'cond' => [
                        'name' => 'post_story_adds_unique',
                    ]
                ]
            ],
    'values.value.like' => 1
])->get();
```

But still i couldn't get the value within the sub-document. I checked the `Builder::project()` function and it seems that it internally use the aggregation framework as well, but i wasn't able to figure out the appropriate syntax to do so, if any.

My questions are as follow:

1- How can i retrieve specific sub-documents' `insights.values.value` and `name` properties, where `name` matches `post_impressions_unique`? An vice versa, how to retrieve the sub-documents' `insignts.values.value.share` and `name` properties when the latter matches `post_story_adds_by_action_type`?

2- What is the correct syntax to use `$filter` within an `$project(aggregation)`?

This is basically most of the research i have been doing, and it feels as if i am running in circles.

Appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this.

Use `$$` notation to access the variable defined in iteration in `$filter` and `$map`.

`$map` is used to trim the response to display `values` and `name` from `insights` array.

```
   [
      [
      '$project' => [
          'insights' => [
              '$map' => [
                'input' => [
                  '$filter' => [
                    'input' => '$insights',
                    'as' => 'insightf',
                    'cond' => [
                        '$or' => [
                          [
                            '$eq' => [
                                '$$insightf.name', 'post_story_adds_by_action_type',
                                ]
                          ],
                          [
                            '$eq' => [
                                '$$insightf.name', 'post_impressions_unique',
                            ]
                          ],
                        ],
                    ],
                  ],
                ],
                'as' => 'insightm',
                'in' => [
                    'values' => '$$insightm.values.value',
                    'name' => '$$insightm.name',
              ],
            ],
          ],
          '_id' => 0
        ],
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: The mapping removed the unnecessary properties such as title, description and period, which is great! Still due to the dissident data structure, the result wasn't as granular as what i would have preferred; for `post_story_adds_by_action_type` get the `share` property of the `value` object, along with the `post_impressions_unique`'s `value` property. Perhaps that would be abusing a document data store by asking it to also cleanse data. I decided to return the metric object up to the `value` regardless of whether it is an object or not. Thanks for your help! Cheers.K.